# Vector erase but I had vector subscript out of range error

Tags: c++, mpc

I want to erase radius < 20, but I received vector subscript out of range error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ball.size() ; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < ball.size(); j++)
    {
        
        int a = ball[i].x - ball[j].x;
        int b = ball[i].y - ball[j].y;
        if (sqrt(a * a + b * b) <= ballr[i]+ballr[j])
        {
            wx[i] = -wx[i];
            wx[j] = -wx[j];
            wy[i] = -wy[i];
            wy[j] = -wy[j];
            ballr[i] =ballr[i]- ballr[i] * 0.1;
            ballr[j] =ballr[j]- ballr[j] * 0.1;
        }
    }
for (int i = ball.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (ballr[i] < 20)
    {
        ball.erase(ball.begin() + i);
    }
    else
    {
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are decrementing `i` twice each iteration that does NOT erase a ball. Consider what happens if all balls are `>= 20`.

Comment: Also: Consider using [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead.

Comment: And if performance matters, consider comparing squared distances instead: `int c = ballr[i]+ballr[j]; if (a*a + b*b <= c*c) {...}`

Comment: I, too often, find myself wandering why the debugger is not the first thing they teach in every programming course

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
for (int i = ball.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (ballr[i] < 20)
    {
        ball.erase(ball.begin() + i);
    }
    else
    {
        i--;
    }
}
```

If, in some case, `ballr[i] >= 20`, then the `else` part got executed, and you decrement `i`. And, at the end of the `for` loop, you decrement `i` once again.

Instead, you want to *increment* `i` when you earse a value.

```cpp
for (int i = ball.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (ballr[i] < 20)
    {
        ball.erase(ball.begin() + i);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-range error is very likely with one of `ballr`, `wx` or `wy` vectors.  Unfortunately, you did not provide the code that allocates them.

In any case, your code is fraught with errors.  I presume you want to detect collisions between moving bubbles of various sizes.

You keep the information for each bubble in several arrays, I see ball[], wx[], wy[],  ballr[]...  **These arrays have to be kept in sync at all times, especially when adding or erasing balls**.  In other words, this arrangement is like calling out for bugs to converge on your code :), as this is the case here.

Have you considered consolidating all information relating to a ball in one place?  This is the basis of OOP, and it would make managing all of this information much easier.

Example:

```
struct ball
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double radius;
    double wx;
    double wy;  

    void reverseCourse()
    {
        wx = -wx;
        wy = -wy;
    }

    // a function to compute distance:
    friend double getDistance(const ball& a, const ball& b)
    {
        double dx = b.x - a.x;
        double dy = b/y - a.y;
        return sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)); 
    }

    friend bool collide(const ball& a, const ball& b)
    {
        return getDistance(a, b) <= (a.radius + b.radius);
    }

};

//...

std::vector<ball> balls;
//...


for (size_t i = 0; i < balls.size(); ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < balls.size(); ++j)
    {
        if (collide(balls[i], balls[j]))
        {
            balls[i].reverseCourse();  // this will probably not work as 
            balls[j].reverseCourse();  // you'd like, a bit of maths 
                                       // will be needed for a more 
                                       // realistic visual effect
            balls[i].radius *= .9;
            balls[j].radius *= .9;
        }
    }
}

// Since all information is kept in one single location, removing balls is a simple operation
// you could do it as you were attempting to do it before (minus the double decrement bug), 
// or using the std library.

// for c++11 and later:
balls.erase(std::remove_if(balls.begin(), balls.end(), 
                          [](const ball& b) { return (b.radius < 20); }),
            bakls.end());

// for c++98
struct local  // any dumb name will do
{
    static bool smallRadius(const ball& b) { return (b.radius < 20); };
};

balls.erase(std::remove_if(balls.begin(), balls.end(), local::smallRadius),
            balls.end());
```